# Movie Clips With Instance Names Crash AIR application

Tags: android, flash, air, instance, movieclip

I have a game that compiles in AIR to android.  This game compiles fine.  I add a movie clip next to another movie clip and the game compiles.

Interesting part:
I add an instance name to this clip and suddenly when running the game, i get white screen.

Any Clues about why flash is having this problem?

I have tried:
Multiple instance names, same thing.
I tried making it a button, game runs but cannot see the movieclip/button.
I tried this removing elements inside the button one at a time and compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck 'Automaticly declare stage instances' in ActionScript 3.0 publish settings.

Comment: I was forgetting to do `public var eBadgeGames :SimpleButton;`